# Compilation message: unchecked method invocation; <t>sort(java.util.list<T>)

Tags: java, arrays, compareto

I am writing code that creates an appointment book and so I have several different classes. I can't see to get rid of this error. It says I have an unchecked method. This is what I get:

`java:25: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: <T>sort(java.util.List<T>) in java.util.Collections is applied to (java.util.ArrayList<Appointment>)`

My code

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*is a collection of Appointment objects. As such, the class must include 
 * a data structure to store an arbitrary number of Appointments*/ 
public class ApptBook  implements Iterable { 

    private ArrayList<Appointment> list; 
    private Date startRange,endRange; 

    public ApptBook(Date _startRange, Date _endRange) 
    { 
        ArrayList ls =new ArrayList(); 
        endRange=_endRange; 
        startRange=_startRange; 

    } 

    public void printAppointments(Date start, Date end) 
    { 
        startRange=start; 
        endRange=end; 
        Collections.sort(list); 

        System.out.println("Result list:"); 
 for(Appointment counter: list){ 
    System.out.println(counter.toString()); 
  } 
    } 


    public void saveToFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    { 
        OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("apptbook.dat"); 
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(f); 
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer); 
        int i; 
        for(i=0;i<list.size();i++) 
        { 
            out.write("##\n"); 
            out.write(list.get(i).forFile()); 
            out.write("#\n"); 
        } 
        out.close(); 
    } 

    public void LoadFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    { 
        InputStream f = new FileInputStream("apptbook.dat"); 
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(f); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader); 
        String str; 
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            if(str.equals("##"))//start read new object 
            { 
                //read date: 
                str = in.readLine(); 
                String []param=str.split(" "); 
                //public Date(int _month, int _day, int _year) 
                // <year>  <month>  <day> 
                Date start=new Date(Integer.parseInt(param[1]),Integer.parseInt(param[2]),Integer.parseInt(param[0])); 
                //read time: 
                str = in.readLine(); 
                String []paramTime=str.split(" "); 
                Time time=new Time(Integer.parseInt(paramTime[0]),Integer.parseInt(paramTime[1])); 
                int duration; 
                str=in.readLine(); 
                duration=Integer.parseInt(str); 
                str=in.readLine(); 
                Appointment newApp=new Appointment(start, time, duration, str); 
                addAppt(newApp);                 
                str=in.readLine();//read # 
            } 
        } 
        in.close(); 
    } 


    //should add a to this ApptBook, provided that a does not overlap  
    //with an Appointment that is already stored.  
    public boolean addAppt(Appointment a)  
    { 
        //check for overlap: 
        int cursor; 
        boolean isOverlap=false; 
        for(cursor = 0;cursor<list.size();cursor++) 
            if(a.overlaps(list.get(cursor))) 
            { 
                isOverlap=true; 
                break; 
            } 
        if(!isOverlap) 
        { 
            list.add(a); 
        } 
        return isOverlap; 
    } 

    public boolean removeAppt(Date d, Time t)  
    { 

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("removal not implemented"); 
    } 

    //@Override 
    public Iterator iterator() { 
        return new ApptBookIterator(list,startRange,endRange); 
    } 

    // Inner class example 
    private class ApptBookIterator implements 
                    Iterator { 
        /* 
         ApptBookIterator 
         */ 
        private int cursor; 
        private Date startRange; 
        private Date endRange;   
        ArrayList<Appointment> list; 

        public ApptBookIterator(ArrayList<Appointment> _list,Date _startRange,Date _EndRange) { 
            list=_list; 
            startRange=_startRange; 
            endRange=_EndRange; 
            //find first in range: 
            boolean isFind=false; 
            for(cursor = 0;cursor<list.size();cursor++) 
            { 
                Appointment temp=list.get(cursor); 
                if(temp.isInDateRange(startRange,endRange)) 
                { 
                    isFind=true; 
                    break; 
                } 
            }            
            if(!isFind) 
                cursor=-1; 
        } 

        public boolean hasNext() { 
            if(cursor==-1) 
                return false; 
            boolean isFind=false; 
            for(int i=cursor;i<list.size();i++) 
            { 
                Appointment temp=list.get(i); 
                if(temp.isInDateRange(startRange,endRange)) 
                { 
                    isFind=true; 
                    break; 
                } 
            }            
            if(!isFind) 
                return false; 
            return true; 
        } 

        public Integer next() { 
            if(this.hasNext()) {              
             for(;cursor<list.size();cursor++) 
                { 
                    Appointment temp=list.get(cursor); 
                    if(temp.isInDateRange(startRange,endRange))                                             
                        break;                     
                }    

            } 
            throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void remove() { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know how to compare that list. You will have to use

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Appointment>() {
    public int compare(Appointment app1, Appointment app2) {
        // Compare your items here
    }
});
```

and specify how to compare two items.

Comment: You could suggest the alternative of making **Appointment** implement `Comparable<Appointment>`, but I'm actually more fond of `Comparator<T>` because it lets you have pluggable comparison and alternate orderings.  Good answer :)

Comment: I've never done it that way, but yeah good call :) Where I work we usually do it like this because we don't always need a list sorted the same way. But it's always good to know the alternatives

Comment: I've always found **Comparable** to be a problem at work. It almost universally needs tweaks and then that opens the class, thus violating the Open Closed Principle.  It's just an ill-conceived interface to begin with.  Then again I'm wickedly spoiled by typeclasses in Haskell ;)